# How to make chocolate cups with swirls?

Tags: chocolate

Can someone please help me with tips to make chocolate cups with swirly designs. Something like [this](http://www.google.com.au/imgres?start=92&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=w5h&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&biw=1252&bih=533&tbm=isch&tbnid=xdKRsMwl8clojM:&imgrefurl=http://www.alexcatering.net/page11.html&docid=215g9IkktGKH7M&imgurl=http://www.alexcatering.net/Quickstart/ImageLib/dessertshells.jpg&w=316&h=316&ei=kMQlUMC-AaSpiAe-toCgCA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=317&vpy=153&dur=2203&hovh=225&hovw=225&tx=41&ty=84&sig=106279950340990633280&page=7&tbnh=144&tbnw=171&ndsp=16&ved=1t:429,r:1,s:92,i:9). I've tried painting the inside of a cup with white chocolate first and letting it set. Once set, I tried painting it with dark chocolate. But somehow, they end up getting mixed and it just comes up as a normal dark chocolate cup.

[image: Chocolate cups]

Comment: I am very surprised to see that you rolled back an edit. It didn't change the meaning of your question, but including the picture in the body made it more likely that somebody will help you, and removing the unnecessary last sentence is standard practice across the network. Did you have any pressing reason to reject the change?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to do it. I went into edit and somehow it ended up rolling it back. I'll fix it soon-ish. But thanks a lot for that. It was a very good suggestion.

Comment: Divi, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried painting the inside of a cup with white chocolate first and letting it set. Once set, I tried painting it with dark chocolate. But somehow, they end up getting mixed and it just comes up as a normal dark chocolate cup.

Comment: I really hope whoever down voted me would tell me what's wrong with my question, so I don't do it again. Its unfair to be down voted and not know the reason for it.

Comment: It probably got voted down because you didn't explain what you'd tried, especially because you can find general instructions online, so, as the text says when you hover over the downvote button, your question didn't show research effort, and was a bit unclear.

Comment: I wasn't the one who voted down, but thanks for editing. It's always best to edit things into the question when people ask for clarification in the comments.

Comment: Thanks anyways. It helps me to form good questions from now on :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to make chocolate cups in general by "painting" a small dish/cup with chocolate, and letting it set in the fridge. If you want tempered chocolate, there are [techniques for that](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21115/is-it-possible-to-temper-chocolate-at-home?rq=1).

But in any case, you've got to consider that different chocolates have different heating/cooling rates, so mixing chocolates with different fat contents (like milk vs dark), or from different manufacturers will (pardon the pun) fudge your calculations a bit as far as how hot/cool the chocolate needs to be. And white chocolate is an entirely different beast, so it has its own melting/setting points to consider as well.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried to do but it failed.

Comment: +1 thanks for the tip. Will google some more about that.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is probably the temperature of the chocolate. As you stated, the chocolates get mixed. That wouldn't happen if the temperature of the chocolate was lower.

Try tempering the chocolate, as MandisaW suggests, before mixing the white chocolate in.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the cups of dark chocolate, then painting the white chocolate stripes on the outside after?  (you might need to paint several layers depending on how thick it is)

If the chocolate is mixing, then the second layer is remelting the first layer - this might be because of relative melting points, so the temperature needed to keep the second layer liquid is just too much higher than the melting point of the first, or it might be because of volume - adding a thick layer over a thinner is much more likely to melt because a thicker layer just has more heat.

So you can switch the order (first the cup, then the stripes) or the layer (paint the cup with the dark and the second layer is white, or the reverse of what you tried) to try and fix the problem mechanically.

Other things you might try include making the whole cup much colder between layers so that the second coat cools faster and doesn't have as much extra heat to melt the first, or just painting on many very thin layers (each layer would then have less heat to waste, cool faster, and give you more control over the design and thickness).  This would be more work, though.